# Do I need to connect company network from home to use company laptop

Tags: tensorflow, proxy, connection

I am using my company's computer at home. Cntlm service is working and configured correctly I believe. But still, when I am trying to install tensorflow, `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` I am getting the following error. I believe I've checked everything, I am using Python 3.5.2. on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, do I need to connect to the company network to use it. The `Proxy 139.23.33.27:81` in cntlm.ini file is a remote proxy address I presume, but I am not sure. I cannot ping to that, and I don't know exactly what is it. Thanks

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object 
at 0 x000000000437EB00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 
10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively 
refused it',))': /simple/tensorflow/
```

cntlm.ini file is configured correctly.

```
Username    myusername
Domain      company.domain
PassLM          80BFA91B8DF323516042EA3C220F09E5
PassNT          6C0D5DCF231C4E4703AE6E3DFAAC321F
PassNTLMv2      0506CK2J7B46282EA8628A6B5A1F57BB    # Only for user

Proxy       139.23.33.27:81
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, *.

Allow 3128
```

Comment: Anybody has comments?